# Trouble reading integer metadata from file

Tags: c++

Trying to read the file size data from a bitmap file. I know that I have the offset (0x02) correct and can find the correct file size in a hex editor.

```
uint32_t getBMPSize(string bmpPath) {
    char sizeread[2] = {};

    uint32_t size;

    ifstream bmpFile;

    bmpFile.open(bmpPath);

    uint16_t offset = 0x02;
    if (bmpFile.is_open()) {


        bmpFile.seekg(offset);
        bmpFile.read(sizeread, 1);

        bmpFile.close();
    }


    size = *sizeread;

    // Convert size from little-endian to big endian
    size = (size >> 24) |
        ((size << 8) & 0x00FF0000) |
        ((size >> 8) & 0x0000FF00) |
        (size << 24);
    



    return size;
}
```

I am expecting to get (8A 7B 0C 00) returned to sizeread. This should then be converted to a big-endian 32bit unsigned integer as 818058. As it stands now, the function returns 2332033023.

Comment: 2332033023 is 8AFFFFFF. You are reading a single character from the file here `bmpFile.read(sizeread, 1);`, which is probably 8A.

Comment: `sizeread` is 2 bytes in length. You say you're expecting 4 bytes, and you read 1 byte.

Comment: Seriously? You expect four bytes, while just reading a single one?

Comment: Had already tried changing sizes of read and of sizeread, and still get the same return value.

Comment: Can't comment on code we can't see. The code we can see is incorrect. I would read 4 bytes directly into a `uint32_t` then byte swap it if you need to.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks. Fixed by reading directly to uint32_t using `bmpFile.read(reinterpret_cast<char*>(&size), 4)`.

Comment: I'd double check the portability of that. I'd also read about `std::bit_cast` and *implicit-lifetime types*.